# How to Replace Blank Indexes in One Dataframe with Indexes From Another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes,  `df1` and `df2`.

`df1` is scraped data:

```
  Name         ID   Symbol
0  AAA   23135106         
1  Bbb  G06242104  String2
2  Ccc  30303M102  String3
3  DDD   2079K305         
4        2079K107
```

And `df2` is reference data:

```
  Name         ID   Symbol
0  Aaa   23135106  String1
1  Bbb  G06242104  String2
2  Ccc  98980L101  String3
3  Ddd   2079K305  String4
4  Eee   2079K107  String5
5  Fff    287Y109  String6
6  Ggg     380105  String7
7  Hhh  G00349103  String8
```

By using `ID` as the key, I want to:

1. populate the empty `Symbols` and `Names` in `df1` with those in `df2`, and
2. replace the malformatted (e.g., AAA vs Aaa) `Names` in `df1` with those in `df2`,

so that the end result looks like:

```
  Name         ID   Symbol
0  Aaa   23135106  String1       
1  Bbb  G06242104  String2
2  Ccc  30303M102  String3
3  Ddd   2079K305  String4       
4  Eee   2079K107  String5
```

Comment: what is the difference between df2 and expected output?

Comment: Sorry, realized I didn't lay this out clearly. I've edited it to make it easier to understand.

Comment: you want to write both `Name` and `Symbol` from `df2` or just `Symbol`?

Comment: `Name` and `Symbol` from `df2`, looking up based on the `ID`. And then if no `Name` and `Symbol` are found, it can return `NaN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need update both `Name` and `Symbol`, you need `update` and slicing assignment

```
df1_1 = df1.set_index('ID')
df1_1.update(df2.set_index('ID'))
df1.loc[df1.Symbol == '', ['Name', 'Symbol']] = df1_1.reset_index()

Out[1238]:
  Name         ID   Symbol
0  Aaa   23135106  String1
1  Bbb  G06242104  String2
2  Ccc  30303M102  String3
3  Ddd   2079K305  String4
4  Eee   2079K107  String5
```

Comment: I get `raise IndexingError(key)
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: (0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: Symbol, dtype: bool, ['Name', 'Symbol'])`

Comment: I am able to reproduce that error when `df1` and `df1_1` got mixed in `.loc` such as `df1_1.loc[df1.Symbol == '', ['Name', 'Symbol']] = ....` Could you double check that in the last command, everything on the left side is `df1` and right side is `df1_1`?

Comment: I see, I think that works for this data, but when I run the code on my actual dataset, I get a `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: oh, it means your actual `df2` has duplicated `ID` values. What do you want to do when `df2` has multiple rows with same `ID`?

Comment: Think I figured that out. Sorry one other question... is there a way to make it so that `ID` appears as a column rather than the index in `df1_1`?

Comment: `update` works on index. To make `update` correctly updates `Name`, `Symbol` by `ID`, `df1_1` must set index to `ID` before call `update`. `df1_1` is just a temp dataframe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205112/discussion-between-msd-and-andy-l).

Comment: Sorry, I can't :(.  I am at work. My company system admin disabled chat. Just edit the question with all updated info, I'll try my best to help

Comment: No worries. I was just saying I'm not sure I understand what you meant by your last comment. Are you saying I should then convert the temp Dataframe to another Dataframe where the `ID` isn't the index and is instead a column?

Comment: ah, I mean `df1_1` is just a middle-man to transfer needed values from `df2` to `df1`. We use `update` to transfer values from `df2` to it, and `.loc` assignment to transfer its selective values to `df1`. So, its purpose is a temp dataframe to achieve our goal. We don't use it after finishing update. I am not sure the reason you want `ID` as column instead of index on `df1_1`, so I emphasized its purpose as a temp dataframe.

Comment: Ahh I see now, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`fillna` and `map` is what you need:

```
df1['Symbol'] = df1.Symbol.fillna(df1.ID.map(df2.set_index('ID').Symbol))
```

Output:

```
  Name         ID   Symbol
0  AAA   23135106  String1
1  Bbb  G06242104  String2
2  Ccc  30303M102  String3
3  DDD   2079K305  String4
4  EEE   2079K107  String5
```

Comment: The output isn't correct. `AAA` should be `Aaa`, `DDD` should be `Ddd` because those are pulling from `df2`.

Comment: I've reworded/reformatted again for additional clarity

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) + [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df1[['Name','ID']].merge(df2[['ID','Symbol']],on='ID',how = 'left').fillna(df1)

  Name         ID   Symbol
0  AAA   23135106  String1
1  Bbb  G06242104  String2
2  Ccc  30303M102  String3
3  DDD   2079K305  String4
4  EEE   2079K107  String5
```

or

```
( df1[['ID']].merge(df2[['Name','ID','Symbol']],on='ID',how = 'left')
             .fillna(df1)
             .reindex(columns = df1.columns) )

  Name         ID   Symbol
0  Aaa   23135106  String1       
1  Bbb  G06242104  String2
2  Ccc  30303M102  String3
3  Ddd   2079K305  String4       
4  Eee   2079K107  String5
```

Comment: The `Name` doesn't seem to be correct. The output returns `AAA` for the `Name` of row 1, when it should be `Aaa`. Same for rows 3 and 4 too.

Comment: the second method returns the correct solution, why don't you use that?